# How do you use the ingest-attachment plugin with elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-model

I was previously using the mapper-attachments plugin that is now deprecated, which was fairly easy to use along with normal indexing. Now that ingest-attachment has replaced it and requires a pipeline, etc. it has become confusing on how to properly use this.

Lets say I have a model named `Media`, that has a `file` field containing the base64 encoded file. I have the following mappings in that file:

```
mapping '_source' => { :excludes => ['file'] } do
  indexes :id, type: :long, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :name, type: :text
  indexes :visibility, type: :integer, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :created_at, type: :date, include_in_all: false
  indexes :updated_at, type: :date, include_in_all: false

  # attachment specific mappings
  indexes 'attachment.title', type: :text, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.author', type: :text, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.name', type: :text, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.date', type: :date, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.content_type', type: :text, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.content_length', type: :integer, store: 'yes'
  indexes 'attachment.content', term_vector: 'with_positions_offsets', type: :text, store: 'yes'
end
```

I have created an attachment pipeline via curl:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/attachment' -d'
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "file"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Now, previously a simple `Media.last.__elasticsearch__.index_document` would have been sufficient to index a record along with the actual `file` via the `mapper-attachments` plugin.

I'm not sure how to do this with `ingest-attachment` using a pipeline and the `elasticsearch-rails` gem.

I can do the following PUT via curl:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/assets/media/68?pipeline=attachment' -d'
{ "file" : "my_really_long_encoded_file_string" }'
```

This will index the encoded file but obviously it doesn't index the rest of the model's data (or overwrites it completely if it was previously indexed). I don't really want to have to include every single model attribute along with the file in a curl command. Are there better or simpler ways of doing this? Am I just completely off with out pipelines and ingest are supposed to work?

Comment: Can you show complete code? I am having trouble setting ingest plugin in rails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I needed up to update the ES gems, specifically elasticsearch-api.

With the mappings and pipeline set as I have it, you can easily just do:

`Media.last.__elasticsearch__.index_document pipeline: :attachment`

or

`Media.last.__elasticsearch__.update_document pipeline: :attachment`

This will index everything correctly and your file will be properly parsed and indexed via the ingest pipeline.